# Entity Framework Invalid Column Name Error

Tags: entity-framework-6

Hi I have class in Entity Framework Like this:-

```
public partial class JLLContact : DomainEntity, IUniqueId
{
    // Simple Props
    public int? Record1ObjectTypeCode { get; set; }
    public int? Record2ObjectTypeCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int JLLContactId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? RoleLid { get; set; }
    public int? BusinessLineLId { get; set; }
    public int? RegionLId { get; set; }
    public int? RelationScoreLId { get; set; }
    public int? RelationStrengthLId { get; set; }
    public int? Record1LId { get; set; }
    public int? Record2LId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public int? CountryLid { get; set; }

    // UniqueId
    public string __Id
    {
        get { return JLLContactId.ToString(); }
    }


    // Parents
    public virtual ListItem Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ListItem Region { get; set; }
    public virtual ListItem Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ListItem BusinessLine { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to add an entry of this type to DB, I get an error. Invalid column Name "BusinessLine_ListItemId", "Country_ListItemId", "Region_ListItemId".
Obviously they are referring to parents properties. But I don't understand the issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this Code First model? Can we see the `ListItem` entity and configuration (if any)?

Comment: @IvanStoev - you were right. The answer lies in the mapping file. I made the changes below and put in the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the Entity Map file. These are the changes I needed to make:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.Role).WithMany(t => t.Role_JLLContacts).HasForeignKey(d => new { d.RoleLid });
this.HasOptional(t => t.BusinessLine).WithMany(t => t.BusinessLine_JLLContacts).HasForeignKey(d => new { d.BusinessLineLId });
this.HasOptional(t => t.Region).WithMany(t => t.Region_JLLContacts).HasForeignKey(d => new { d.RegionLId });
```